# Reproducing PHPs hash_hmac functionality in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, cryptography

I'm creating a more secure user password table with the username, a strongly random salt, and a salted/hashed password in php like so:

```
$salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
$pass = hash_hmac('sha512', $plainTextPass, $salt);
$this->user->password = $pass;
$this->user->salt = $salt;
$this->user->save();
```

I'm trying to reproduce this functionality in MySQL without much luck. I need to create some users when the DB server is deployed from a script. As I understand it the hash_hmac method just takes the salt, appends the password to it, then hashes it with sha 512. Seems like this would be easy enough to do in MySQL, but this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `username`, `password`, `salt`) 
VALUES('test@example.com', 'admin', SHA2('9d1ebf3559baf9ffca61df5cec0b9eb067ae7912d097ad45f3a3086c39bf11292d92a7dfad497557fac7fbf7c24209db8b7696664d54c7e6bc55f720121bd38dadmin', 512), '9d1ebf3559baf9ffca61df5cec0b9eb067ae7912d097ad45f3a3086c39bf11292d92a7dfad497557fac7fbf7c24209db8b7696664d54c7e6bc55f720121bd38d');
```

In this case the salt is just a hard coded one I generated manually, and you can see I just append the password "admin" on to the end of it for the password field. This user creates, but I can't login with that admin username and password.

Should I be doing this a different way in MySQL?

Comment: Can you just pre-compute some hashes and use those?

Comment: I would be more inclined to keep processing and data storage separate, create your hashes in PHP using `crypt` then save them to the database.

Comment: Yes I could to both those questions, but to automate the spinning up many VMs and make changing passwords easier it would make my life easier to be able to solve this in the MySQL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is not computed by concatenation, but as follows (see the link for more details).

HMAC (K,m) = H ((K ⊕ opad) ∥ H ((K ⊕ ipad) ∥ m))

However, as the name implies, it is a message authentication code, not a password hashing scheme. An algorithm that is designed for password hashing would be a better choice. [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) would be a good bet.